# Java Jackson 2.8.3 serializing list containing abstract objects with circular dependencies

Tags: java, jackson

I try to serialize some data with jackson which works pretty well for most cases but now I have an issue with a list. The list is of type A which is an abstract class and may contain circular dependencies. I can't figure out how to serialize this construct with jackson. The combination of identityInformation and typeInformation doesn't seem to properly work.
Below is Examplecode which produces the issue I am facing.

I am using Jackson version 2.8.3. Am I missing something? Is there a good solution to serialize and deserialize this kind of list?

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

public class JacksonTest {

    @JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "@class")

    @JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class) })
    public static abstract class A {
        public A member;
    }

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
    public static class B extends A {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        B instance1 = new B();
        B instance2 = new B();
        instance1.member = instance2;

        list.add(instance1);
        list.add(instance2);

        CollectionType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(list.getClass(), A.class);

        try{
            String serialized = mapper.writerFor(listType).writeValueAsString(list);
            System.out.println(serialized);
            list = mapper.readValue(serialized, listType);          
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Generated json String:

```
[{"@class":"JacksonTest$B","@id":1,"member":{"@class":"JacksonTest$B","@id":2,"member":null}},2]
```

Error when trying to read the String:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@class' that is to contain type id  (for class JacksonTest$A)
```

It seems like jackson expects the second entry to also be a json object containing the @class field and doesn't recognize that the second array element is a reference to an already existing object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type of field "A.member" is "A"  and you missed out @JsonIdentityInfo for "A" type.  Due to this, Jackson consider the object from list is a normal object( only id was serialized) and due to lack of identityinfo, jackson is not able to apply the object reference lookup mechanism during de-serializing and hence you see the error.

To fix your issue you need to add "@JsonIdentityInfo for type "A" too or better you can move @JsonIdentityInfo declaration from type "B" to "A".

code:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.sameInstance;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hamcrest.core.IsSame;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

public class JacksonTest {

    @JsonTypeInfo(
                  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
                  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
                  property = "@class")

    @JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class) })
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
    public static abstract class A {
        public A member;
    }

    public static class B extends A {
    }

    @Test
    public void testCirularPolymorphicSerialization() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // set up fixture
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
        B instance1 = new B();
        B instance2 = new B();
        instance1.member = instance2;
        list.add(instance1);
        list.add(instance2);

        CollectionType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(list.getClass(), A.class);
        String serialized = mapper.writerFor(listType).writeValueAsString(list);
        list = mapper.readValue(serialized, listType);

        assertThat(list.size(), is(2));
        assertThat(list.get(0).member, sameInstance(list.get(1)));
    }
}
```